# Number of paths in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

A  `p x q` size matrix is given, and a matrix of size `a x b` is removed from top right corner. Find the total no. of paths from top left to bottom right, with only right and down movements allowed. No path should go into the removed matrix.

eg-

```
 _
|_|_
|_|_|
```

this is `(2x2)` matrix after removing `(1x1)` matrix from top right corner. no. of ways - `5`.

I am able to find out the total number of paths, but the method I am thinking of eliminating the paths that go into the removed portion is very elementary and hence not efficient.

So, are there any better algorithm for it ?

Comment: Think of a general directed acyclic graph. There's a linear-time algorithm in the number of vertices if you have the graph's topological sort. This translates to a quadratic algorithm in the size of the matrix.

Comment: Are you looking for combinatorial (math) solution or an algorithmic one? Note that the graph representing your matrix is a DAG, so if you are looking for algorithmic solution, this should probably be used.

Comment: this can be solved in linear time in the size of the grid (assuming constant-time math).

Comment: "Better" than what?  You claim to have been able to find the total number of paths.  Please post how in the question.

Comment: I developed a math solution and it involved a summation of all the paths entering into the removed path from all possible points and coming out from all possible points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exploit the structure of the grid:

The number of paths from one corner to the other on a square grid is given by the size of the grid by the pascal's triangle: `(x+y) choose x`

Each path must cross exactly one point on each diagonal.

Take all points on the diagonal that passes through the inner corner, calculate the number of paths through each, and sum.

This leads to an `O(min(p-a, q-b))` algorithm assuming constant-time arithmetic.

In your case: (two paths to the center) * (two paths from the center) + (one path through the corner) = (four paths through the center) + (one path through the corner) = (five paths)

```
+-+-+
| | |
+-+-A-+-+
| | | | |
+-B-+-+-+
| | | | |
C-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+

  (1+2) choose 1 * (2+3) choose 2 (through A)
+ (2+1) choose 2 * (3+2) choose 3 (through B)
+ (3+0) choose 3 * (4+1) choose 4 (through C)

= 3 choose 1 * 5 choose 2
+ 3 choose 2 * 5 choose 3
+ 3 choose 3 * 5 choose 4

= 3*10
+ 3*10
+ 1*5

= 30+30+5 = 65 paths
```

Comment: I developed it as well and got to a similar solution, sum the result of: for each i in [0,q-a] `chose(i+b,q-a) * chose(q-a+p-b,p-b)`. (The number of ways to get to each of the the squares in the lowest line in a `q-a * p-b` rectangle, multiply by the number of paths from the square down from it to the end).  Both are valid of course.

Comment: @amit are you sure you won't get duplicate paths?

Comment: @acbruptenda what about now?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Positive, those are distinct paths, each "element" in the summation is `i` "right" steps until a certain (well defined) line, for different `i`s you must get distinct paths, multipiled by distinct paths from the square down to it to the end

Comment: @amit if you take `i` right steps, the next step must be down, otherwise you actually do `i+1` right steps. Do you account for that?

Comment: yes. do i steps, the next is always down (the square below) and "count" the numbet of steps from the square below.

Comment: So you actually cut along the edges just above the cutout? This seems like a good idea (and slightly easier to implement than mine).

Answer (score 6):

Do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)<sup>1</sup> representing the problem.

Then iterate from last (sink) to first (source):

```
f(v) = Sum(f(u)) for each (v,u) in E
base: f(sink) = 1
```

Complexity is linear in the size of the graph (iterating each vertex exactly once) (Using the dimensions of the matrix it is `O(p*q-a*b)`)

---

(1) The graph G=(V,E) is:

```
V = { (i,j) | for each i,j in the matrix that was not deleted }
E = { ((i1,j1),(i2,j2)) | (i1,j1) is to the left/up of (i2,j2) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assume we are moving from m,n to 1,1
int  numberOfPaths(int m, int n)
{
/*If the m,n  is left-bordered to the removed matrix, then move only downwards 
  till the end of removed matrix,then we can move in two directions*/
 //l1=numberOfrows(bigMatrix)-numberOfRows(smallMatrix), similarly l2 for columns
 if(m==l1&&n>=l2)
   return numberOfPaths(l1-1,l2+2)+numberOfPaths(l1,l2+1);
// If either given row number is first or given column number is first
if (m == 1 || n == 1)
    return 1;

 return  numberOfPaths(m-1, n) + numberOfPaths(m, n-1); 
}
```